AppiumWebDriverEventListener not working with katalon
Have a good day.
I am using the below class to listen for clicks and usages. and code being used for hybrid app that works on both android and iOS.
Code for listener in katalon
import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject

import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint as Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling as FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase as TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData as TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject

import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile

import internal.GlobalVariable
import io.appium.java_client.events.api.general.AppiumWebDriverEventListener
import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.BeforeTestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.BeforeTestSuite
import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.AfterTestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.AfterTestSuite
import com.kms.katalon.core.context.TestCaseContext
import com.kms.katalon.core.context.TestSuiteContext

class ClickEventListener implements AppiumWebDriverEventListener {

    @Override
    public void afterAlertAccept(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterAlertDismiss(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1, CharSequence[] arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterClickOn(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        System.out.println("afterClickOn ---");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public <X> void afterGetScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> arg0, X arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterGetText(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1, String arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateBack(WebDriver arg0) {
        
        System.out.println("navigate back <---");
        
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateForward(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateRefresh(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateTo(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterScript(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterSwitchToWindow(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeAlertAccept(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeAlertDismiss(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1, CharSequence[] arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeClickOn(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public <X> void beforeGetScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeGetText(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateBack(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateForward(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateRefresh(WebDriver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateTo(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeScript(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeSwitchToWindow(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Throwable arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement var1, WebDriver var2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement var1, WebDriver var2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
  
    
    
}

and this is the code for test case, in which I have registerd the test listener there (just temorary)
AndroidDriver<?> driver = MobileDriverFactory.getDriver()

// Create an instance of your ClickEventListener class
ClickEventListener clickListener = new ClickEventListener();
EventFiringWebDriver eventFiringDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
eventFiringDriver.register(clickListener)




Mobile.pressBack()

String loginButtonSource = "Object Repository/StartPage/loginButton";
TestObject loginButton = findTestObject(loginButtonSource)

Mobile.tap(loginButton, 10, FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE)


I have tried to test methods [afterClickOn, afterNavigateBack] but they are not fired.
